# What is a female worker who receives a salary called?

Tags: words, katakana

I have seen the term サラリーマン for men. What is a female who works for a salary, regardless of occupation, called?　Is サラリーウーマン appropriate?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6137/what-is-the-difference-between-%e3%82%ad%e3%83%a3%e3%83%aa%e3%82%a2%e3%82%a6%e3%83%bc%e3%83%9e%e3%83%b3-ol-and-%e3%83%93%e3%82%b8%e3%83%8d%e3%82%b9%e3%82%a6%e3%83%bc%e3%83%9e%e3%83%b3/6138#6138

Comment: my question is specific to the female equivalent term for salaryman regardless of occupation. The salaryman term is not addressed in that question or answer.

Comment: Right, and that question discusses the options. Keep in mind that a サラリーマン in Japanese is not a word for "a man who earns a salary regardless of occupation." Many occupations that are salary-based would not be included in サラリーマン.

Comment: My question is specific to salaried female employees

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We don't use サラリーウーマン. **OL (pronounced オーエル)** is a catch-all, wasei-eigo term for female office workers. Don't try to "spell it out" as オフィスレディー, which is usually **not** understood.

However, some people believe it mainly refers to low-ranking workers who does clerical work, and even [English Wikipedia article for this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_lady) is written with such a prejudiced view:

> OL is a female office worker in Japan who performs generally pink collar tasks such as serving tea and secretarial or clerical work.

The [Japanese version](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/OL) says it's essentially a neutral term. If you want to avoid misunderstanding, it's safest to just use **会社員** regardless of sex. サラリーマン is becoming a dated word, anyway.

**EDIT**: Note that both サラリーマン and OL mainly refer to **office** workers. Blue-collar workers are usually not called サラリーマン even if their income is salary-based.

Related

- [What is the difference between キャリアウーマン, OL, and ビジネスウーマン?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6137/5010)